# Blurry but HD Render - How do I make it sharper?

Tags: rendering, animation

I've new to animating with Blender and I'm having troubles with my rendering.
(Note: These are two still images of the same frame out of my animation project)

The thing is that it is supposed to look like this:
[image: Correct Image]
But.. When rendered, it comes out like this:
[image]

What's wrong and how do I fix it? 
(Note: I know about the Black background in the second image, and how to fix it.)

**EDIT - Blend File: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/29219**

Comment: Do post the blend file.

Comment: Are you doing any defocusing or playing with the depth of field?

Comment: A nice blender specific hosting site you can use is http://pasteall.org.

Comment: Here you go: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/29219

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found out why it was blurred. As @cegaton suggested - It was a defocus node that was added . . .

Can be found in node editor (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd>) as said in the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Composite_Nodes/Types/Filter#Defocus).